# Default AsyncCallback in GWT

Tags: gwt

Doing my app, I got bored from always implement the same default error treatment (show a message, caught.printstacktrace and etc..) in the asynccallback onfailure.

I wonder if you can make a generic treatment or standard treatment, something like that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I assume you are using standard GWT-RPC. Something like this might help

```
public abstract class AbstractCallBack<T> implements AsyncCallback<T>{
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
        //Default error Handling code goes here
    }
}
```

And whenever you use your service instead of instantiating an AsyncCallback you can instantiate this class and have generalized error handling.

```
SomeServiceAsync service = GWT.create(SomeService.class);
service.someMethod("Hello!", new AbstractCallBack<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub              
    }
});
```